# Java: A "prime" number or a "power of two" as HashMap size?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

Many books and tutorials say that the size of a hash table must be a prime to evenly distribute the keys in all the buckets. But Java's `HashMap` always uses a size that is a power of two. Shouldn't it be using a prime? What's better, a "prime" or a "power of two" as the hash table size?

Comment: I doubt that they really say exactly that, and if they do they are wrong. That's only one way of doing it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using a power of two effectively masks out top bits of the hash code. Thus a poor-quality hash function might perform particularly badly in this scenario.

Java's `HashMap` mitigates this by mistrusting the object's `hashCode()` implementation and [applying a second level of hashing to its result](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#256):

> Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which defends against poor quality hash functions. This is critical because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ in lower bits.

If you have a good hash function, or do something similar to what `HashMap` does, it does not matter whether you use prime numbers etc as the table size.

If, on the other hand, the hash function is of unknown or poor quality, then using a prime number would be a safer bet. It will, however, make dynamically-sized tables tricker to implement, since all of a sudden you need to be able to produce prime numbers instead of just multiplying the size by a constant factor.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why? (or do you have reference/links that explain this)?

Comment: Are you sure the size of the table doesn't matter? Isn't the point of a good hash function to spread the data out across the table, in order to reduce the number of collisions? But if the table is very small, then collisions will increase, regardless of the hash function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pamphlet: It's clear that bigger is better (or least unlikely to be worse). However, for similar sizes, there's no reason to prefer prime numbers etc, *as long as the hash function is of high quality*.

Comment: @pamphlet: I've reworded that part of the answer since it wasn't very clear what I meant.

Comment: @pamphlet The capacity of the table is increased (by approximately a factor of two) when the load factor is exceeded, so even if the initial capacity of the table is very small, the table will expand to a suitable size for the maximum number of entries contained. A good initial guess means less resizing as the table grows, but a bad initial guess will still eventually produce an efficient table.

Answer (score 6):

The standard HashMap implementation has a `hash` method which rehashes your object's hashcode to avoid that pitfall. The comment before [the `hash()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#255) reads:

```
/**
 * Retrieve object hash code and applies a supplemental hash function to the
 * result hash, which defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is
 * critical because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
 * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
 * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
 */
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way to know which is better between prime and power-of-two is to benchmark it.

Many years ago, when writing an assembler whose performance depended strongly on symbol talbe lookup, I tested this using a large block of generated identifiers. Even with a naive mapping, I found that power-of-two, as expected, had less even distribution and longer chains than a similar sized prime number of buckets. It still ran faster, because of the speed of bucket selection by bit masking.

I strongly suspect the java.util developers would not have resorted to the extra hashing and power-of-two without benchmarking it against using a prime number of buckets. It is a really obvious thing to do when designing a hashed data structure.

For that reason, I'm sure the rehash and power-of-two size gives better performance for typical Java hash maps than a prime number of buckets.

Comment: .NET implementation of HashMap (they call it Dictionary) uses a hardcoded list of prime numbers for bucket size. So, I wouldn't be so sure about the advantage of rehash vs. primes, at least I wouldn't generalise this conclusion to other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

From a performance/calculation time point of view power-of-two sizes can be calculated with just **bit masking** which is faster than **integer modulo operation** which would be required otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use prime sized hash tables if you use [quadratic probing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing) for collision resolution. If you have a prime sized table, quadratic probing will hit half of the entries, less if it is not a prime. So you might not find a suitable place to store you entry even if your hash table is less than half full. Since Java hash maps don't use quadratic probing, there is no need to use primes as size.