# Set minimum size of a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, size

In my program key-value pairs are frequently added to a `Map` until 1G of pairs are added. Map resizing slows down the process. How can I set minimum `Map` size to, for example 1000000007 (which is a prime)?

Comment: Use the constructor that takes the initial size?

Comment: Will the constructor prevent map from resizing down?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not do any research at all. There is a constructor for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @Stepan, Why don't you just read the documentation about how `initialCapacity` is used?

Comment: HashMap should have a size that is prime to minimize clustering.

Comment: @Stepan http://stackoverflow.com/a/15437377/438992

Comment: Well, I got the answer. Gotta delete the question now. Thanks for all downvotes. Answerer's efford is wasted though.

Comment: @Stepan Then don't delete it--I didn't downvote, but I  mean, come on, it's right there in the docs :/

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) takes the initial size of the map (and the load factor, if desired).

```
Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<>(1_000_000_007);
```

Comment: See [HashMap Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-int-) for additional info, if this answer isn't clear enough.

Comment: I would recommend to write `1_000_000_007` for readability reasons.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I set minimum Map size to, for example 1000000007 (which is a prime)?

Using the `HashMap(int)` or `HashMap(int, float)` constructor.  The `int` parameter is the capacity.

> HashMap should have a size that is prime to minimize clustering.

Past and current implementations of the `HashMap` constructor will all choose a capacity that is the smallest power of 2 (up to 2<sup>30</sup>) which is greater or equal to the supplied capacity.  So using a prime number has no effect.

> Will the constructor prevent map from resizing down?

HashMaps don't resize down.

---

(Note that *size* and *capacity* are different things.  The `size()` method returns the number of currently entries in the `Map`.  You can't "set" the size.)

Comment: Actually, this was his question, not how to create a map with an initial size.

Comment: @ROMANIA No, the initial question was how to create a map with a minimum size. It's right there in the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton , it's debatable, but he wanted (according to the title) to **Set minimum size of a Map in Java**, not **Set initial size of a Map in Java**. This is what I understand - that he believed that the `HashMap` will reduce its size during some actions and he wanted to fix a minimum size.

Answer (score 2):

A could of things you should note. The number of buckets in a HashMap is a power of 2 (might not be in future), the next power of 2 is 2^30.  The load factor determines at what size it should grow the Map. Typically this is 0.75.

If you set the capacity to be the expected size, it will;

- round up to the next power of 2
- might still resize when the capacity * 0.75 is reached.
- is limited to 2^30 anyway as it is the largest power of 2 you can have for the size of an array.

> Will the constructor prevent map from resizing down?

The only way to do this is to copy all the elements into a new Map. This is not done automatically.

Comment: Actually, the number of buckets in **_the current implementation_** of `HashMap` is a power of 2.  It probably will not change, but that implementation detail is *not* part of the interface contract and shouldn't be relied on.  It may not always be a power of 2.